# How to fix 'Policy operations on v2 application are disabled' in AzureADPreview Windows PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, token, lifetime

I have registered a multi-tennant app in Azure AD and I would like to extend the lifetime of the access and refresh tokens the users who sign into my app receive. Despite creating a default policy for tokens, the access token my user receives is 1 hour.

The policy I have created is:

> New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('{"TokenLifetimePolicy":{"Version":1,"AccessTokenLifetime":"23:00:00","MaxInactiveTime":"90.00:00:00","MaxAgeSingleFactor":"until-revoked","MaxAgeMultiFactor":"until-revoked","MaxAgeSessionSingleFactor":"until-revoked","MaxAgeSessionMultiFactor":"until-revoked"}}') -DisplayName "OrganizationDefaultPolicyScenario" -IsOrganizationDefault $true -Type "TokenLifetimePolicy"

Considering how my policy is probably not being applied to users who sign in from other tenants, I tried applying it specifically to my app using:

> Add-AzureADApplicationPolicy -Id  -RefObjectId 
>   but I was presented the error:
>
> Add-AzureADApplicationPolicy : Error occurred while executing AddApplicationPolicy
>
> Code: Request_BadRequest
>
> Message: Policy operations on v2 application are disabled.
>
> InnerError:
>     RequestId: ...
>     DateTimeStamp: Mon, 02 Sep 2019 20:39:54 GMT
>   HttpStatusCode: BadRequest
>   HttpStatusDescription: Bad Request
>   HttpResponseStatus: Completed
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Add-AzureADApplicationPolicy -Id  ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-AzureADApplicationPolicy], ApiException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.MSGraphBeta.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.MSGraphBeta.PowerShell.AddApplica
>      tionPolicy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Add-AzureADApplicationPolicy cmdlet is not available at this time
>   .

You can find this message at the top of the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/add-azureadapplicationpolicy?view=azureadps-2.0-preview).

[image]

However, I just tested it on my side, **it will work if you don't choose personal account as the account type**.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for finding the solution, Tony! Sadly it seems I will have to settle for the default token lifetime configuration since I want personal accounts to have access to my application.

Answer (score 2):

Application for any tenant will not be able to add the Azure AD Policy, this issue needs to be considered as by design since the Azure AD Policy is considered a v1 policy and this can’t be applied on a V2 application.

Here is the response on the question:

```
Some policies are blocked for converged Applications, since they are not supported by MSA (Microsoft Account) and Azure AD.
  The Configurable Token Lifetime will be deprecated later this year and replaced by an new feature for Conditional Access policy.
  So, we are not planning to invest into Configurable Token Lifetime to discourage taking dependencies with it.
```

In the second paragraph noted as important the configurable token lifetime policy will be deprecated, please check the information bellow:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! Despite being deprecated I understood it could still be used and Tony Ju explained how.